# Called as vs known as

Tags: word-difference

> 1) Mango is known as the King of fruits
>   2) Mango is called as the King of fruits

I find this “called as" vs "known as” thing quite confusing...Which of these sentence is appropriate to use while writing?

Comment: Why do you think "called as" is usable? If you found some usage, you might add examples.

Answer (score 1):

In this context "called" means the same thing as "known as".

But if you used "called" you do not add "as".

**"Mango is called the king of fruits". "Mango is known as the king of fruits".**